# How to re-create function with same name in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I need to re-create a group of functions but I don't want to check their parameters to use drop if there are functions with the same names but different parameters.
Is this possible to drop/recreate them only by name?

Or is this possible to catch exceptions, raise errors and continue to execute the transaction?

I'm trying to do it using

```
DO $$ 
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test(id integer)
                 RETURNS text[]
                 LANGUAGE plpgsql
                AS $function$
                begin
                    
                end;
                $function$
                ; 
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN duplicate_function THEN RAISE NOTICE 'already exists';
        END;
    END;
$$;
```

But It completes scripts quietly and does not raise any errors.

Comment: Hmm, `CREATE OR REPLACE` will do what it says, replace it, when it's already there, so why would you expect an exception "`duplicate_function`" would be thrown?

Comment: Why would you expect that to raise an error?

Comment: If you are changing the parameters `CREATE OR REPLACE` will create the function with  same name but a different signature, in other words it will `overload` the function. See [CREATE FUNCTION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) for more info. An error will be thrown if you change the `return` type though.

Comment: But if I changer `CREATE OR REPLACE` to `CREATE` why it still not raising my error message? I'm getting [42723] error, as I understand this is a duplicate_function error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that 42723 is raised when a named object already, However, it is **not a named exception**. Thus your exception handles does not recognized, so it takes no action. You can get what you want by directly referencing the SQLSTATE and your error code.

```
DO $$ 
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            CREATE FUNCTION public.test(id integer)
                 RETURNS text[]
                 LANGUAGE plpgsql
                AS $function$
                begin
                    
                end;
                $function$
                ; 
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN SQLSTATE '42723' THEN RAISE NOTICE 'already exists';
        END;
    END;
$$;
```

`Raise notice` sends the text following to sysout, which is often not accessible in a production system. You might want to change to `raise exception`.